# Using resizebox around equation environment gives "Missing $ inserted"

Tags: errors

I want to use `resizebox` around some content which contains, among other things, an equation environment. However, this produces a "Missing $ inserted" error. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\resizebox{!}{.5cm}{%
    \begin{equation*}
    H^1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}x\hspace{0.3cm},\hspace{0.25cm} H^3(S^3)=\mathbb{Z}y
    \end{equation*}%
}
\end{document}
```

As I said, this produces the following error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.10 }
```

Does anyone know what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: I don't think you can use display math in a resizebox without introducing paragraph mode with a `\parbox` or similar. In this case, I suspect it would be better to just use inline math mode instead, unless you had a strong reason to want to use `equation*`. Does it look like you want if you change `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}` to `\(...\)`?

Comment: You say “among other things”, but the example only has a single equation. Can you please make a more detailed example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

After the frabjous's suggestion You can have centered resized formula without errors with this code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe} % comment this line after testing rhe code
\begin{document}
    \noindent   Some text:\par
    \vspace{.3cm}
    \begin{center}
        \resizebox{!}{.5cm}{%
            \(
            H^1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}x\hspace{0.3cm},\hspace{0.25cm} H^3(S^3)=\mathbb{Z}y
            \)%
        }\par   
    \end{center}
    \vspace{.3cm}
    Some text.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]